# Extra characters in PHP email "from" field

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send email from PHP, and although it's working, I'm noticing that I'm getting a lot of extra stuff in the "from" part of the email. The extra stuff, I'm **assuming**, is
information from my server?

For example, if `$from = "myname"`, instead of `"myname"` only coming through in the email from field as is, I get something like:

> myname@p3nlhg.phx3.secureserver.net

Here is my PHP I'm playing with, the important part being my `$from` var:

```
$from = "myname";

mail($to,$formSubj,$formMssg,$from);
```

Honestly that's all I have, nothing more or less (as far as the `$from` is concerned). How can I clean this up or make it so that only the plain value of `$from`, which is in this case `"myname"`, comes out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4th parameter of the mail function doesn't work this way. It expect header information. To achieve what you want to do use:

```
$header = "From: myname <no-reply@test.com> \r\n";
mail($to,$formSubj,$formMssg,$header);
```

You shouldn't use a lonely `myname` either. You need a valid email addess string: `myname <no-reply@test.com>` or `no-reply@test.com`. If you just put `myname`, PHP will try to interpret it as an email address. That's why you're getting `myname@p3nlhg.phx3.secureserver.net`. `p3nlhg.phx3.secureserver.net` must be the hostname of your server.

A nice thing about the header parameter is that you can use it to specify other less common fields. e.g.:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Notice that you need to place a carriage-return/line-feed (`\r\n`) at the end of each header attribute. A simple line feed will not work.

Comment: the part that says "<birthday@example.com>" whos email is that supposed to be?

Comment: Your answer worked, and it cleaned up the header "from" field. my question is, when i added(copy/paste) your stuff above(i edited it of course) it doesnt work, when i remove this line " $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; " , it works. know why? and is it important?

Comment: The MIME-Version header is for all intents and purposes useless. So you don't need to specify it. For an explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME-Version

That part of the answer was just an example to show what sort of things you can specify in an email header. I didn't write it myself it comes from a comment on the PHP mail function doc page (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3150)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`mail` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), you're using `$from` as the `$additional_headers` argument.

Instead, change `$from` to an appropriate header. For example,

```
$from = "myname";
$headers = "From: $from <user@example.com>";
mail($to, $formSubj, $formMssg, $headers);
```

According to the documentation for `additional_headers`,

> When sending mail, the mail ***must*** contain a ***From*** header. This can be set with the ***`additional_headers`*** parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to **Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing**. The ***From*** header sets also ***Return-Path*** under Windows.

Answer (score -1):

It's coming from the mail server that you have installed in your server, try to switch to another one, like postfix, courier or someting else.